# How to prove the trigonometric inequality without differentiating?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

$2\sin x +\tan x > 3x$

$0 < x < \pi/2$

How to prove the above inequality?

Comment: Over what range for $x$?

Comment: clearly wrong for $x=0$

Comment: Also not true for $x\in(\pi/2,\pi)$

Comment: Does a Taylor series count as differentiating?

Comment: how to solve with that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by $AM\ge GM$ and we get

$$\dfrac{\cos x+\cos x+\sec^2 x}{3}\ge(\cos x\cdot\cos x\cdot\sec^2x)^\frac13$$
$$\dfrac{\cos x+\cos x+\sec^2 x}{3}\ge1$$
$$2\cos x+\sec^2 x\ge3$$
$$2\cos x+\sec^2x-3\ge0,x\in(0,\pi/2)$$

Comment: He said *without* differentiating.

Comment: How did u get the AM part

Comment: By differentiating $\sin x+\sin x+\tan x$

Comment: Can anybody find any way without differentiation

Comment: Why do you specifically need it without differentiation

Comment: To know if it is possible

Comment: @gokuladethya I can only think of this method to solve that problem.