Proving $\tan x+2\sin x>3x$ Using Mean Value Theorem
Proof:

$\tan x+2\sin x>3x, 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$

Using Mean Value Theorem.  I first let $f(t)$ be $\tan t + 2\sin t- 3t$ so that I can change the prove slightly. $f(t)$ is differentiable at $(0, x]$ so I can use mean value theorem. There is a $c \in (0,x]$ such that
$$
f'(c)=\sec^2
c+2\cos c-3 = f(x)/x$$
The problem is that I can't find any way to prove $f'(c)$ is greater than $0$. I tried:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{\cos^2c}+2\cos c-3=f(x)/x \\
\cos^2c(1+2\cos^3c-3\cos c)=f(x)/x\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
and I got stuck.
Edit: Thank you for people answering my questions! I'm dumb and didn't read the guidelines clearly before posting this question. I hope this question can help other people.

Sorry for not giving my attempt! I tried a little bit with f'(c)=sec^2c+2sinc-3c but got stuck at proving f'(c) must be greater than 0. If f'(c) is greater than 0 then the whole question got solved.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3244083/42969

Let $f(x)=\tan x+2\sin x-3x$, then $f'(x)=\sec^2x+2\cos x-3$. Since $x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, $\cos x>0$. To verify that $f'(x)>0$, it is the same to verify that $g(x)=2\cos^3-3\cos^2+1>0$. Note that $2t^3-3t^2+1=(t-1)^2(2t+1)$ and since $(\cos x-1)^2(2\cos x+1)>0 $ when $x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, we have $f'(x)>0$. Then, since $f(0)=0$, by the Mean Value Theorem, for all $y\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, we have $f(y)-f(0)=f(y)=f'(\xi)y>0$ for some $\xi \in(0,y)$.
